# Error "Unable parse file browser.yml" when running a test with Magento automation test framework

Tags: magento, automation

I have tried to run a test with magento automation framework, but the result shown as "no testcase execute" and error on output shown as

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unable to parse file "C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\config\browsers.yml": Unable to parse line 27 (---).' in E:\xampp\php\pear\SymfonyComponents\YAML\sfYaml.php:100
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\lib\Mage\Selenium\Helper\File.php(52): sfYaml::load('C:\Users\huongn...')
#1 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\lib\Mage\Selenium\TestConfiguration.php(387): Mage_Selenium_Helper_File->loadYamlFile('C:\Users\huongn...')
#2 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\lib\Mage\Selenium\TestConfiguration.php(264): Mage_Selenium_TestConfiguration->_loadConfigData()
#3 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\lib\Mage\Selenium\TestConfiguration.php(163): Mage_Selenium_TestConfiguration->_initConfig()
#4 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\lib\Mage\Selenium\TestConfiguration.php(147): Mage_Selenium_TestConfiguration->init()
#5 C:\Users\huongnguyen\mtaf\bootstrap.php(44): Mage_Selenium_TestConfiguration::initInstance()
#6 E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php(92): include_once('C:\Users\huongn...')
#7 in E:\xampp\php\pear\SymfonyComponents\YAML\sfYaml.php on line 100
```

Anyone ever met like before?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this by upgrading the Symfony Yaml package to the latest version:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install symfony/YAML
```

Seems that the "---" syntax is supported on v. 1.0.6 (the latest stable at this moment).